# Function comes back undefined(javascript)

Tags: javascript, math

Good morning,

I hope I am asking this correctly per guidelines. I am taking a course and am stuck on exercise 6. I was given limited information but have to solve this code.

My task is -

Rocket Cars wants you to create a function to calculate how many weeks it would take to sell all their cars. Your function contains 2 parameters:

```
The average number of cars sold per day
The number of cars currently in the dealership
```

Your function must be named 'SalesCalculator' and has to return a number which represents the amount of weeks it would take to sell all their cars.

To do so: divide the number of cars in the dealership by the average number of cars sold per day Multiplied by 5. Your function must return the result of this equation.

I was given this code to start with -

```
function SalesCalculator(amountOfCars, averageSoldPerDay) {
    return //code goes here
}
```

I have tried a bunch of ways but keep coming back with multiple different errors depending on what coding I try.

I have tried-

```
function SalesCalculator(amountOfCars, averageSoldPerDay) {
            return (amountOfCars / averageSoldPerDay) * 5;
         }
```

```
function SalesCalculator(amountOfCars, averageSoldPerDay) {
    let amountOfCars = a;
    let averageSoldPerDay = b;
    return a / b * 5;
}
```

```
function SalesCalculator(amountOfCars, averageSoldPerDay) {
    console.log(a / b * 5);
}
```

None of these have been accepted and I have tried a thousand different ways but so far I seem to be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.

Thanks!

Comment: Your grouping of operations is wrong –  *divide the number of cars in the dealership by the average number of cars sold per day Multiplied by 5* -> `cars/(avg*5)`

Comment: As pilchard says, your grouping of operations is wrong. Take step back and think about the expected result of the function by entering values which you know should produce an expected return value. For example, if I have 5 cars, and sold an average of 2 per day, your function says it would take 12.5 weeks to sell all of the cars - which is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! You guys are amazing and I really apprecaite your help. I definately grouped them wrong and when I fixed it, it was correct. Thank again :)